# how to resolve slow image reading speed in android?

Tags: android

I am reading images from sdcard using this code. But when I start the app it takes upto 5 seconds to start. Can you give me some suggestion how can I reduce that time of reading the images. This is the code --

```
ArrayList<File> imageReader(File root){

    ArrayList<File> a = new ArrayList<>();
    b = new ArrayList<>();

    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    for (int i=0;i<files.length;i++){
        if (files[i].isDirectory()){

            a.addAll(imageReader(files[i]));
        }
        else{

            if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")) {

            a.add(files[i]);

            }
        }
    }

return a;
}
```

Comment: How many images do you have? Obviously your code will make the app stuck as you're going this on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the Recursion**

```
public static List<File> getAllFiles(File root) {

   List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
   files.addAll(Arrays.asList(root.listFiles());
   List<File> images = new ArrayList<File>();
   for (int i=0; i < files.size(); i++) {
      File aFile = files.get(i);
      if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
          files.addAll(Arrays.asList(aFile.listFiles());
          continue;
      }
      if (aFile..getName().endsWith(".jpg")) {
         images.add(aFile);
      }
   return images;
}
```

**Use a background thread**

```
new Thread() {

   public void run() {
      System.out.prinln(getAllFiles(File.listRoots()[0]);
   }
}.start();
```